# Vi error: Line too long

Tags: vim, text, vi

I am using **vi** to open and edit a file. After switching to 'insert mode' by pressing 'i', when I start to write after just a few characters (I wanted to write "adress: street etc.") I get a message:

```
a
ad
adINSERT MODE
Line too long
:ess: Not an editor command
```

Can somebody suggest me how I can change the default text length?

Comment: Is your `r` key is remapped to something in your vimrc file?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge No, it is not. The same error I have when I write only aaaaaaaaaa or any other long sequence of characters

Comment: Is this when editing a line that's already long? I understand vi has limits on line length (which aren't present in vim, for example).

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge No, it is when I want to write something to an empty file

Comment: can you post the :version output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12276362/1821490